# "Pixel format of incoming image is unsupported by OpenCV" on Jetson Nano

Tags: python, opencv, v4l2, nvidia-jetson, nvidia-jetson-nano

This code

```
cap = cv2.VideoCapture('/dev/video0', cv2.CAP_V4L2)
```

gives

> VIDEOIO ERROR: V4L2: Pixel format of incoming image is unsupported by OpenCV

Here is the output of `v4l2-ctl -d /dev/video0 --list-formats`:

```
ioctl: VIDIOC_ENUM_FMT
    Index       : 0
    Type        : Video Capture
    Pixel Format: 'RG10'
    Name        : 10-bit Bayer RGRG/GBGB
```

Here is my OpenCV:

```
-- OpenCL samples are skipped: OpenCL SDK is required
-- 
-- General configuration for OpenCV 4.1.2-pre =====================================
--   Version control:               4.1.1-365-g9efafc3e3
-- 
--   Extra modules:
--     Location (extra):            /home/sovlyn/Downloads/opencv_contrib/modules
--     Version control (extra):     4.1.1-62-g83e98d24
-- 
--   Platform:
--     Timestamp:                   2019-10-10T09:26:02Z
--     Host:                        Linux 4.9.140-tegra aarch64
--     CMake:                       3.10.2
--     CMake generator:             Unix Makefiles
--     CMake build tool:            /usr/bin/make
--     Configuration:               RELEASE
-- 
--   CPU/HW features:
--     Baseline:                    NEON FP16
--       required:                  NEON
--       disabled:                  VFPV3
-- 
--   C/C++:
--     Built as dynamic libs?:      YES
--     C++ Compiler:                /usr/bin/c++  (ver 7.4.0)
--     C++ flags (Release):         -fsigned-char -W -Wall -Werror=return-type -Werror=non-virtual-dtor -Werror=address -Werror=sequence-point -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wmissing-declarations -Wundef -Winit-self -Wpointer-arith -Wshadow -Wsign-promo -Wuninitialized -Winit-self -Wsuggest-override -Wno-delete-non-virtual-dtor -Wno-comment -Wimplicit-fallthrough=3 -Wno-strict-overflow -fdiagnostics-show-option -pthread -fomit-frame-pointer -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections    -fvisibility=hidden -fvisibility-inlines-hidden -O3 -DNDEBUG  -DNDEBUG
--     C++ flags (Debug):           -fsigned-char -W -Wall -Werror=return-type -Werror=non-virtual-dtor -Werror=address -Werror=sequence-point -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wmissing-declarations -Wundef -Winit-self -Wpointer-arith -Wshadow -Wsign-promo -Wuninitialized -Winit-self -Wsuggest-override -Wno-delete-non-virtual-dtor -Wno-comment -Wimplicit-fallthrough=3 -Wno-strict-overflow -fdiagnostics-show-option -pthread -fomit-frame-pointer -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections    -fvisibility=hidden -fvisibility-inlines-hidden -g  -O0 -DDEBUG -D_DEBUG
--     C Compiler:                  /usr/bin/cc
--     C flags (Release):           -fsigned-char -W -Wall -Werror=return-type -Werror=non-virtual-dtor -Werror=address -Werror=sequence-point -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wmissing-declarations -Wmissing-prototypes -Wstrict-prototypes -Wundef -Winit-self -Wpointer-arith -Wshadow -Wuninitialized -Winit-self -Wno-comment -Wimplicit-fallthrough=3 -Wno-strict-overflow -fdiagnostics-show-option -pthread -fomit-frame-pointer -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections    -fvisibility=hidden -O3 -DNDEBUG  -DNDEBUG
--     C flags (Debug):             -fsigned-char -W -Wall -Werror=return-type -Werror=non-virtual-dtor -Werror=address -Werror=sequence-point -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wmissing-declarations -Wmissing-prototypes -Wstrict-prototypes -Wundef -Winit-self -Wpointer-arith -Wshadow -Wuninitialized -Winit-self -Wno-comment -Wimplicit-fallthrough=3 -Wno-strict-overflow -fdiagnostics-show-option -pthread -fomit-frame-pointer -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections    -fvisibility=hidden -g  -O0 -DDEBUG -D_DEBUG
--     Linker flags (Release):      -Wl,--gc-sections  
--     Linker flags (Debug):        -Wl,--gc-sections  
--     ccache:                      NO
--     Precompiled headers:         NO
--     Extra dependencies:          dl m pthread rt
--     3rdparty dependencies:
-- 
--   OpenCV modules:
--     To be built:                 aruco bgsegm bioinspired calib3d ccalib core datasets dnn dnn_objdetect dnn_superres dpm face features2d flann freetype fuzzy gapi hfs highgui img_hash imgcodecs imgproc line_descriptor ml objdetect optflow phase_unwrapping photo plot python3 quality reg rgbd saliency shape stereo stitching structured_light superres surface_matching text tracking ts video videoio videostab xfeatures2d ximgproc xobjdetect xphoto
--     Disabled:                    world
--     Disabled by dependency:      -
--     Unavailable:                 cnn_3dobj cudaarithm cudabgsegm cudacodec cudafeatures2d cudafilters cudaimgproc cudalegacy cudaobjdetect cudaoptflow cudastereo cudawarping cudev cvv hdf java js matlab ovis python2 sfm viz
--     Applications:                tests perf_tests examples apps
--     Documentation:               NO
--     Non-free algorithms:         YES
-- 
--   GUI: 
--     GTK+:                        YES (ver 2.24.32)
--       GThread :                  YES (ver 2.56.4)
--       GtkGlExt:                  NO
--     VTK support:                 NO
-- 
--   Media I/O: 
--     ZLib:                        /usr/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libz.so (ver 1.2.11)
--     JPEG:                        /usr/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libjpeg.so (ver 80)
--     WEBP:                        build (ver encoder: 0x020e)
--     PNG:                         /usr/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libpng.so (ver 1.6.34)
--     TIFF:                        /usr/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libtiff.so (ver 42 / 4.0.9)
--     JPEG 2000:                   build (ver 1.900.1)
--     OpenEXR:                     build (ver 2.3.0)
--     HDR:                         YES
--     SUNRASTER:                   YES
--     PXM:                         YES
--     PFM:                         YES
-- 
--   Video I/O:
--     DC1394:                      YES (2.2.5)
--     FFMPEG:                      YES
--       avcodec:                   YES (57.107.100)
--       avformat:                  YES (57.83.100)
--       avutil:                    YES (55.78.100)
--       swscale:                   YES (4.8.100)
--       avresample:                NO
--     GStreamer:                   YES (1.14.5)
--     v4l/v4l2:                    YES (linux/videodev2.h)
-- 
--   Parallel framework:            TBB (ver 2017.0 interface 9107)
-- 
--   Trace:                         YES (with Intel ITT)
-- 
--   Other third-party libraries:
--     Lapack:                      NO
--     Eigen:                       YES (ver 3.3.4)
--     Custom HAL:                  YES (carotene (ver 0.0.1))
--     Protobuf:                    build (3.5.1)
-- 
--   OpenCL:                        YES (no extra features)
--     Include path:                /home/sovlyn/Downloads/opencv/3rdparty/include/opencl/1.2
--     Link libraries:              Dynamic load
-- 
--   Python 3:
--     Interpreter:                 /usr/bin/python3 (ver 3.6.8)
--     Libraries:                   /usr/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libpython3.6m.so (ver 3.6.8)
--     numpy:                       /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/numpy/core/include (ver 1.17.2)
--     install path:                lib/python3.6/dist-packages/cv2/python-3.6
-- 
--   Python (for build):            /usr/bin/python3
-- 
--   Java:                          
--     ant:                         NO
--     JNI:                         NO
--     Java wrappers:               NO
--     Java tests:                  NO
-- 
--   Install to:                    /usr/local
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using pi-cam on jetson, then use below pipe line to get video stream from MIPI CSI camera:

```
cv2.VideoCapture('nvarguscamerasrc ! video/x-raw(memory:NVMM), width=(int)640, height=(int)480, format=(string)NV12, framerate=(fraction)60/1 ! nvvidconv flip-method=0 ! video/x-raw, format=(string)BGRx ! videoconvert ! video/x-raw, format=(string)BGR ! appsink', cv2.CAP_GSTREAMER)
```

Change `flip-method` to 0 or 2 (for more options, see [here](https://developer.download.nvidia.com/embedded/L4T/r32-2_Release_v1.0/Accelerated_GStreamer_User_Guide.pdf?RkM0J4D5Pg6bLnBt3vBo7-y808bMeLspU7-Z5jHXhAs3pL2ykHKYEusXStgBK7SSKhpbgytIWz0V24NmHWfb8_0CVjsYsMKVrgj2OPNM4Hg2pCgAPFPijg06NM2h3rzG2Ikw5L6tMf2EMGiupGWN_nz5Be7TITxC3jdRpxcVCrDAJnk)).
Good luck!